# Safari -webkit-box-reflect for video not working

Tags: css, reflection, safari, video.js, 360-panorama

I have a website where I'm using [Videojs-panorama](https://github.com/yanwsh/videojs-panorama)

When I create reflection of this video using `-webkit-box-reflect` it is working fine in chrome and opera.

But in safari the canvas is not getting reflected instead only video is reflected.

Any help will be really appreciated.